# I have a NTFS partition now the size of the partition seems to be wrong. Is there an easy way to fix this?

Tags: partition, partition-table, ntfs

So I I resized a partition and now the partition table seems like it is screwed up. I am running Windows 7. When I open the "Disk Management" The table at the top of the screen show the disk as 139GB. Down below, in the graphical partition representation, it shows as 212GB. It is truly 212GB. The rest of the OS sees it as  139GB... why is this inconsistent two pieces of the same Disk management app are showing different sizes for this partition. Is there a way to repair this? Manually or automatically?

Comment: I have the same problem when I extended an NTFS partition using gparted. The partition was resized but the volume isn't...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's possible for the partition to be a different size than the NTFS volume inside the partition. NTFS maintains a count of the allocation units in the volume irrespective of the partition size. Having an NTFS volume show as *larger* than the partition its in is bad mojo, but smaller is no big deal.

It's unclear to me *how* your machine would've gotten that way, but it's certainly possible.

I'd recommend running CHKDSK on the volume to be sure it's healthy, and, of course, being sure that you've got a good backup before proceeding.

- Boot your Windows 7 installation CD and at the "Install Windows" dialog, press <kbd>Shift-F10</kbd> to open a command prompt.
- At the command prompt, run `diskpart`.
- At the `DISKPART>` prompt, enter `list disk` to see the disks on your machine. You'll get something like:

```
    Disk ###  Status      Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
    --------  ----------  -------  -------  ---  ---
    Disk 0    Online        96 GB      0 B
```

- Enter `select disk #` where # is the disk number listed for your hard disk drive (most liekly 0).
- Enter `list partition`. You'll get something like:

```
  Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset
  -------------  ----------------  -------  -------
  Partition 1    Primary             96 GB    32 KB
```

- Enter 'select partition #' where # is the partition number associated with your "C:" "drive".
- Finally, use the command `extend`. This will grow the NTFS volume to fill the partition.

Comment: As a comment to Evan's answer: I had to use the undocumented diskpart command extend filesystem as referenced <a href="https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/832316">here</a>. Doing only *extend* told me that the device does not have any more space.

Comment: Not working for me, as ending up with the message: `There is not enough usable free space on specified disk(s) to extend the volume.` . Context: cloned to larger drive, moved recovery partition to end of drive and expanded Windows partition. New partition scheme correctly detected by diskpart, but in Windows the C:\ drive kept its original size.

Answer (score 10):

There is another scenario that is common if you clone your HDD to a larger one OR if you have a VPS/Virtual Server and resize the disk what happens is that usually the partition will remain the same/wrong size even though Disk Manager will show it as the new larger size.

In the case of the above this would be the required solution:

```
list volume
select volume #
extend filesystem
```

(note the filesystem after the extend otherwise you will get a minimum extent error because you would be telling diskpart to extend the disk instead of have the OS recognize the new size).

Comment: Many many thanks! It works! And important is to type `extend filesystem` as Areeb Soo Yasir mentioned, and not only `extend`. For some unknown reason, something was corrupted and the volume displayed as `RAW` instead of `NTFS`. However, I could expand it, and then perform a startup repair (using a recovery installer USB of Windows). Windows checked the filesystem and everything was fixed.

Comment: Resolved my problem after cloning to a larger drive with Clonezilla. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.  I used driveimage xml to create an image of an 80GB drive and restore it to a new 320GB drive.  After restoration the C: drive was reporting 79GB and the partition manager was showing the 298GB partition with no space available.  I followed above but used the Microsoft DiskPart commands:
list partition and extend filesystem.  Then ran the disk utilities.  After booting Windows Explorer showed the full 298GB with 75GB used.  Even though old thread, hope this helps.

Comment: The accepted answer does suggest exactly the same thing. Not sure what new your post brings to the table.

Answer (score -1):

I can only guess here, but I assume that your partition is only 139GB in size. You can resize it by using [Acronis Disk Director](http://www.acronis.com/enterprise/products/diskdirector/) or any other tool that allows to resize partitions.

Best wishes,
Fabian

Answer (score -1):

The discrepancy makes me think HD problems.  Backup first, even before running chkdsk! Copy the data to another physical drive, make an image of the drive if you want a 2nd backup.  Run chkdsk with verify/repair. If the drive has underlying issues you'll want to deal with that before making any changes.

If chkdsk comes back clean or minor errors found and repaired but size mistmatch still exists then I would boot off a live CD live CD like System Rescue CD and see how it lists the partition size.  You can use ParImage on that cd to change the partition size if needed but that may be addressing a symptom and not the cause.  Acronis has also great products for imaging and changing partition sizes, not free but affordable for workstation OS's.

[SystemRescueCD](http://www.sysresccd.org/Main_Page)